# How to fix Set Backup Attributes Error in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvsKl.png)

I have done my project view on android studio kotlin, and when I run it on the emulator it doesn't show any error but the app is forced to close, then I open the manifest.xml and there is a warning there told me to set the backup attributes, and then a add the allowbackup and fullbackupcontent to True but is still showing the same error, please help me to fix this otherwise my application couldn't run well

Thank you anyway :)

[is this the stack trace? I'm sorry but I was a beginner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMPzQ.png)

Comment: Post the `stacktrace` from logcat, the warning in manifest is not an error.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMPzQ.png
actually im not sure that this is the stack trace but I found it in logcat

Comment: Please post text as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to hide that warning;

```
<application
       ...
       tools:ignore="Allowbackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Comment: I already hide it and it fix the warning, but the problem is my application is still force closing

Comment: it should have differant reason then, i believe this warning won't crash the app